# Raku signature (Array @r) is not (Array:D)?

Tags: polymorphism, raku

I can not seem to make head or tails of this Raku error message I found while exploring grammars...

---

```
Cannot resolve caller report(Array:D); none of these signatures matches:
(Array @r)
(Match $r)
```

---

So an Array is not an Array?!  How does that work and how do I find out why?
Here is the full program and output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
grammar Integers {
    rule TOP      { ^ .*? <targets> .* $  }
    rule targets  { <integer>+ % ',' }
    token integer { \d+ }
}

multi sub report(Array @r) { say @r.raku }
multi sub report(Match $r) { say $r.raku }

sub MAIN() {
    my $result = Integers.parse(' a 1234 ');
    report($result);
    report(%$result{'targets'});
    report(%$result{'targets'}{'integer'});
}
#`( output:
Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(0), :pos(8), :hash(Map.new((:targets(Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(8), :hash(Map.new((:integer([Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7))]))))))))))
Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(8), :hash(Map.new((:integer([Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7))])))))
Cannot resolve caller report(Array:D); none of these signatures matches:
    (Array @r)
    (Match $r)
  in sub MAIN at /home/hans/Programming/Raku/Parsing/Array_Array.raku line 16
  in block <unit> at /home/hans/Programming/Raku/Parsing/Array_Array.raku line 3
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear confused about the functionality of sigils and typing.

When you use the `@` sigil, you are implying a [`Positional`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Positional) constraint.

```
sub foo(@a) { ... }
```

will take anything that does the `Positional` role.

```
foo( @b );
foo( [1,2,3] );
foo( (1,2,3) );
```

When you specify a type with a `@` in a signature, you're indicating that you want a `Positional` that only accepts *that* type as its elements.  Now, as a parameter to a subroutine, that severely limits what you can specify, as `[1,2,3]` is **not** an array with a constraint on `Int`, it's an array that happens to be filled with `Int` values only.

Now back to your example: what does `(Array @r)` mean?  It means that you want a `Positional` that constrains on `Array` objects.  In simple terms: you want an array that *must* consist of arrays as its elements.

I don't think that is what you intended?

Now, why does `(Array $r)` work?  Because that indicates you want an object that is an `Array` as the parameter.  This also limits what you want, because then it *has* to be an `Array`, and cannot be a `List` for instance.

```
sub foo(Array $r) { ... }
foo(@a);         # works
foo( [1,2,3] );  # works
foo( (1,2,3) );  # does *not* work
```

Finally, I think you want to use the built-in [`dd`](https://docs.raku.org/programs/01-debugging#index-entry-dd) instead of building your own `report` function.

Comment: So `(Array @r)` could be described as array of arrays r, or as array of `Positional`s r? As for why I am re-implementing dd, that's how I am learning the syntax for accessing Match object properties.

Comment: `Positional @r` would be an array of `Positional`s, so `Array @r` is indeed an array of `Array`s.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I have a partial answer to my own question.
If I change (Array @r) to (Array $r) of if I just drop Array and use (@r).

Per [docs.raku.org](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem) "If no type is provided by the user Raku assumes the type to be Any". So that explains why (@r) works.  It just (Any @r)...I think.

As for why (Array:D) must be coded as (Array $r), I'm still trying to figure that one out.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: You could code it as `Array:D $r` if you wanted. The more generic `Array $r` will work as well, but is more generic -- it will accept an `Array` even if it's just an `Array` type object not an instance.

Answer (score 4):

Hi @FyFAIR and welcome to raku. IMO raku is an awesome tool, but there are few guardrails. So please be patient, since when it clicks, it will be worth it ;-)

I have taken the liberty of re-drafting your example the way I would do it:

```
grammar Integers {
    token TOP      { ^ .*? <targets> .* $  }
    token targets  { <integer>+ % ',' }
    token integer { \d+ }
}

sub MAIN() {
    my $result = Integers.parse(' a 1234 '); 
    dd $result;
    dd $result<targets>;
    dd $result<targets><integer>;    #<== a list of matches with one element
    dd $result<targets><integer>[0];
    say "$result<targets><integer>[0]";
}

Integers $result = Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(0), :pos(8), :hash(Map.new((:targets(Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7), :hash(Map.new((:integer([Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7))]))))))))))
Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7), :hash(Map.new((:integer([Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7))])))))
[Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7))]
Match.new(:orig(" a 1234 "), :from(3), :pos(7))
1234
```

So... here are my remarks:

- you are very close (!)
- @lizmat's guidance on `dd` has served me well
- use `@` as the sigil for @lists unless you want a surprise
- just use `token` unless you really need `rule`
- types are great for checks and multis ... I get my code functional without types first and then gradually layer them in so I can see if they are doing the job
- `Int @array` means that the capture will check for e.g. `my Int @array = [1,2,3]` which (as lizmat says) is not the same as an array with Int values `[1,2,3]` (here the type check is delegating the control of what is assigned to the array)
- no need for perl style derefs like `%$`
- `<key>` is the same as `{'key'}` but less typing
- the Match object is very complex and powerful ... dd shows the innards, but this is usually overkill
- use `say` and stringify the Match with `""` (or `.Str`) to get the thing you really need
- `use Grammar::Tracer;` is you friend

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite and remarks, especially `Grammar:Tracer`.